# Fragments mapping Error Code First Migration - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm in trouble with this entity.

Even if I Ignore a ValidationResult field, it's returning an error.
The database it's correctly generated, but the seed method does not run.

My Entity

```
public class Noticia : ISelfValidation
    {
        public int NoticiaId { get; set; }

        public int PoliticoId { get; set; }

        public string Titulo { get; set; }

        public string Corpo { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataPostagem { get; set; }


        public virtual ValidationResult ValidationResult { get; private set; }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                var validation = new NoticiaIsValidValidation();
                ValidationResult = validation.Valid(this);
                return this.ValidationResult.IsValid;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Fluent Config

```
 public class NoticiaConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Noticia>
    {
        public NoticiaConfig()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.NoticiaId);
            Property(x => x.NoticiaId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            Property(x => x.Corpo)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsMaxLength();


            Ignore(x => x.ValidationResult);

            Ignore(x => x.IsValid);
        }
    }
```

And the error Log

```
PM> Update-Database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201512161825183_AutomaticMigration.
Running Seed method.
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: 
(223,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 223:No mapping specified for properties Noticia.ValidationResult in Set Noticias.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
  Entity is type [GestaoPolitica.Infra.Data.Context.Noticia]

   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGenerateViews(EntityContainerMapping entityContainerMap, Dictionary`2 resultDictionary)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitSortOp(SortBaseOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(ConstrainedSortOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ConstrainedSortOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet`1 set, IEnumerable`1 identifyingProperties, InternalSet`1 internalSet, TEntity[] entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet`1 set, TEntity[] entities)
   at GestaoPolitica.Infra.Data.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(GestaoPoliticaContext context) in C:\Users\AS\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GestaoPolitica\GestaoPolitica\GestaoPolitica.Infra.Data\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 19
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

Comment: Didn't see your edit until after I posted my answer. You might want to move that Ignore to the `OnModelCreating` override in the DbContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Entity Framework that it shouldn't map to a database object by marking your property with the `[NotMapped]` attribute or use the `Ignore()` method from fluent API in the DbContext's `OnModelCreating` override method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Noticia>(t => t.IsValid);
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Noticia>(t => t.ValidationResult);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```